# List of things to check before turning on SQL Server CLR?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sqlclr

I am trying to deploy a CLR function (which computes a hash of a text or a file, not available from SQL Server) for the first time on a production server.

I was able to test the function on a development machine but I am still wondering,

**Are there any list of *gotchas* to consider before turning on the CLR option?**

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll find all (or at least a goodly amount) of the info you want at this MSDN article directly related to the subject:

[**CLR Integration Security**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131071(SQL.90).aspx)

Although I doubt that it directly relates to your situation, I have seen one big gotcha when calling unmanaged code from an an assembly.  Something along the lines of [**this post**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlnetfx/thread/64695da6-4b7f-42dd-bb51-6e524c8603cb).

Also, any dependencies that your assembly requires also have to be registered with SQL.  Even things like System.dll.  That can get ugly.  Very few assemblies are blessed by SQL by default.

Comment: @squilman: Not exactly an answer to my question but worth knowing those implications on using SqlCLR; Thanks.

Comment: @Sung Meister: what type of info are you looking for then?

Comment: @squilman: sorry about the delay on response.  I have decided not to go with SQL CLR for the particular problem I was having - I created a windows services instead.

Comment: Old post I know but just came across it - there are a number of assemblies already available - including System.dll - the full list for SQL Server 2005 can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279%28v=sql.90%29.aspx (page also has a link to other SQL Server versions which have added more assemblies - e.g. 2014 also supports System.Xml.Linq.dll)